# UILabel text scaling incorrectly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I was having some issues with UILabel in a large project I am working on so I decided to try to reproduce them in a fresh project. The results I got shook my understanding of how UILabels work particularly in reference to the property "adjustFontSizeToFitWidth." The code below results in the image.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"TEST";
label.font = [[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:100.0];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100);
[label.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[view addSubview:label];
```

[image: UILabel created with above code]

So my question is why wasn't the text font adjusted to ACTUALLY fit the width of the UILabel's frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:100.0];` will not produce a valid instance because you don't specify a font name, so the label will use the default font. So it appears to exactly what it should. Try creating the font properly and re-running your test.

Comment: Long story short, this problem was hidden WAY down in my app somewhere... More proof for me that no matter how long I work on things and how much I learn, I will always make a stupid mistake now and again... Thanks for setting me strait.

Comment: The problem with `[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:100.0];` is that a valid font is never initialized. This should be `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:100];` or the call to `fontWithSize:` should be called on an existing `UIFont` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[mylabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:128.0]];

Thanks